# pass array via session and fetch information based on it

Tags: forms, session, view, controller, laravel-5.6

On one page, I would like to store a dynamic form in the database, and on the next page, I will list these items and, based on that, I have another form to be recorded in the table.
But when I do this, I have an error. My source code and error are as follows. please guide me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

my problem solved by insert row then fetch last record and insert to variable.

```
DB::table('travelers')->insert([
'faName' => $this->first_name[$i],
'faFamily' => $this->last_name[$i],
'fatherName' => $this->father_name[$i],
'nationalCode' => $this->national_code[$i],
'phone' => $this->phone_number[$i],
'enName' => $this->e_first_name[$i],
'enFamily' => $this->e_last_name[$i],
'email' => $this->email[$i],
'passportNumber' => $this->passport_number[$i],
'expDate' => CustomDateTime::toGreg($this->passport_expire_date[$i]),
'birthDay' => CustomDateTime::toGreg($this->birthday[$i]),
'foreigner' => $foreignerField
```

]);
$traveler = DB::table('travelers')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();